# How to parse different type of arguments?

Tags: c, terminal, command-line-arguments, getopt

My program needs to support getting these arguments through the terminal :

- -stdin followed by a random amount of numbers
- other long type of options followed either by one number or none
- files
- websites

The problem I have is that although getopt works for the first two cases it doesn't seem to work for files and websites as they don't start with "-". Is there a way to make it work or do I have to get through *argv[] with a for loop and some kind of pattern matching ?

Comment: *argv[] with a for loop and some kind of pattern matching ? Is exactly what you should do. Loop, strcmp, and then do with [i] and [i+1] as you must.

Comment: Can you compare only the first 4 letters of a string with strcomp ? Like could I only check if my argument starts with http ?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
```

You can go through each string in argv and parse it in whatever way you need.

I do not believe there is a more eloquent solution

Answer (score 0):

The first solution comes up to mind can be parsing `argv` input strings appropriately as the way your program logic requires. On the other hand, you may want to use more elegant way to take care of any patterns you are searching for. At this point, **regular expression** is your friend. You can include `regex.h` in your source code and dive into miracle world of regexp.

Check this out: [Regular Expression in C](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/regex.h.html)